# Svchost using high cpu while computer on idle

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-services, windows-10-v2004, high-cpu-usage

I've been dealing with high fan noise while my laptop screen turns off and goes idle. I ran performance monitor while this happens found 2 svchost files going 50% and 30% cpu usage. But could not tell which svchost process is causing the problem since the monitor only shows process name.
I then tried procmon to check only svchost process usage. Found these below. From the 5 million registry event to the highlight 1.2 listed below (this is over a few minutes to let the screen to go idle and fans to ramp up)

- C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted -p
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService -p -s Dnscache
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted -p -s EventLog
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k AarSvcGroup -p -s AarSvc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBDMc.png (I am not allowed to post images smh)
and after adding the network process activity the high network usage one is

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService -p -s Dnscache

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1gWF.png

I could try disabling services one by one used by these processes. But maybe someone can suggest a better way to identify which one of these is the actual problem service.

Also I did save the procmon output to a file in case i need to return to it.